# Почему срабатывает media query когда он не должен срабатывать?

Tags: css3, media-queries

Есть [сайт](http://ask-carol.com/), на которой есть такой CSS стиль:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px){
    #top.page-id-122 #layer_slider_1 .avia-button:not(.avia-button-fullwidth) {
       width: 78px;
       min-width: 109px ; 
    }
    #layer_slider_1 .avia-button-wrap{
        width: calc(-50%);
        height: calc(-50%);
    }
    .main_menu{
        width: calc(-35%);
    }
    .avia-menu-text{
        padding: 0;
        margin: -7px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Почему этот код срабатывает на моем ноутбуке 1366 пикселей ширина экрана?
[image]

Comment: Идем от обратного: почему вы думаете, что он срабатывает? Что видно в инспекторе?

Comment: @Etki я вижу на ноутбуке, когда открываю сайт... Добавил скриншот!

Comment: @eprivalov1, ага. И как нам быть уверенными, что проблема именно в том, что конкретно этот кусок неправильно срабатывает (и девелоперы мозиллы/гугла/майкрософта ни на что не годны), а не вернулся старый кэш / это другие стили так влияют / ваше "вижу" на самом деле вас обманывает?

В инспекторе (F12) можно посмотреть все стили, которые применяются к конкретному элементу.

Comment: у вас 43 css and 43 js - и все они работают?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fask-carol.com%2F + <head> не закрыт

Comment: @soledar10 Я не знаю, сайт достался от индусов ;-(